# Wrap text in SVG images when importing them in latex using inkscape=true

Tags: wrap, svg, inkscape

I make graph using [draw.io](https://draw.io) that I export in SVG to include in my LaTeX document. However some texts are too long and don't fit well when using the `inkscape=true` option of `\includesvg`

```xml
<path d="M 40 497 L 120 577" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none" />
<path d="M 120 497 L 40 577" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none" />
<rect x="400" y="597" width="80" height="80" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" pointer-events="none" />
<rect x="400" y="597" width="80" height="80" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" stroke="#ff0000" pointer-events="none" />
<g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)">
    <switch>
        <foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe flex-start; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 1px; height: 1px; padding-top: 684px; margin-left: 440px;">
                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;" data-drawio-colors="color: #FF0000; ">
                    <div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: none; white-space: nowrap;">This text is wayyyyyyyyyy too long to fit under the square.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
        <text x="440" y="696" fill="#FF0000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">This text is wayyyyyyyyyy too long to fit under the square.</text>
    </switch>
</g>
```

[image: Text isn't wrapping under in graph]

I'm including the SVG in my LaTeX document like that (I'm using the exam document class):

```latex
\framedsolutions\SolutionEmphasis{\bfseries\color{black}}
\begin{solutionorbox}[\stretch{1}]
    \centering
    \fontsize{8}{10}
    \includesvg[inkscapelatex=true,width=\linewidth]{solution-schema-controle-5}
\end{solutionorbox}
```

**Is there any way to make the text wrap to not exceed the width of the square?**

Comment: Try to use parbox or minipage

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I resolved my issue modifying my SVG manually like this. Instead of this line containing all of my text:

```xml
<text x="440" y="696" fill="#FF0000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">This text is wayyyyyyyyyy too long to fit under the square.</text>
```

I separated it inside the `<text>` tag using `<tspan>`. Note that `sodipodi:role="line"` attribute is important to tell Inkscape that this tspan is not inline but represents a separate line.

```xml
<text x="440" y="696" fill="#FF0000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">
    <tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="tspan100" style="font-size:12px" x="440" y="696">This text is</tspan>
    <tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="tspan101" style="font-size:12px" x="440" y="696">wayyyyyyyyyy too long</tspan>
    <tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="tspan102" style="font-size:12px" x="440" y="696">to fit under the square.</tspan>
</text>
```

Here's the result:

[image: Text wrapping in a graph]

Answer (score 0):

Try to put Your image with box in one of the next construction like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % new package from Martin scharrer
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption for image}
    \label{fig:sample_figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```